# How to change http nginx timeout in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I know the exact variables that I need to change in the Nginx conf file, that is: `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

And these are the fields, that I want to change:

```
http {
     fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
     proxy_read_timeout 300;
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to do it with Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide nginx settings using `.platform` as explained in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

Therefore, you could have the following `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconfig.conf` with content:

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
proxy_read_timeout 300;
```

If this will not work, you may need to overwrite entire `nginx.conf` providing a custom version in `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf`, rather then using `myconfig.conf` above. To do this, ssh into your EB instance, check original `nginx.conf`, copy it, modify and provide a modified version as `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf`.